# CloudKit (a background process) and UI communication

Tags: swift, ios8, cloudkit

I have a login screen. The user enters username and password then clicks login. Then the class connects to database loads the data and returns true or false.

However, because the perform query operation is done in a different thread, the Load function always returns false. But the debugging shows successful load of the data.

If I were doing the database loading from within the UIController then, putting the database blocks in the following was working beautifully:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

After I separated the UI from the Model, the above no longer works.
How would I go about background database operations and know that it is indeed finished?

On the view controller I have this code:

```
            if mainPerson.isLoaded() != true {
                let result = mainPerson.load()
                NSLog("Person loaded from database result: \(result)")
            }
```

Which always returns false.

The load method is as follows:

```
func load() -> Bool {
    var loadSuccess : Bool = false

    let username = self.email

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email = %@", username)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "PatikoyUsers", predicate: predicate)

    // run the query
    database.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {
        (records: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            NSLog("There is an error fetching user: \(error)")
            loadSuccess = false
        } else {
            // show record count and records
            NSLog("User fetched, \(records.count) record(s) found")
            for rec in records as [CKRecord] {
                NSLog("Records = \(rec)")
            }
            if records.count == 0 {
                loadSuccess = false
            } else {
                // user found, check password
                NSLog("User found. Loading...")

                self.record = records.first as CKRecord

                self.name = self.record.objectForKey("name") as String
                self.password = self.record.objectForKey("password") as String
                self.verified = self.record.objectForKey("verified") as Bool

                NSLog("User password is: \(self.password)")

                self._isChanged = false
                loadSuccess = true
            }
        }
    })

    self._isLoaded = loadSuccess
    NSLog("ReservationPerson loading result: \(loadSuccess)")
    return loadSuccess
}
```

Which always returns false.  Sorry for the long question. Hopefully it has an easy answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not let that method return the success status of the operation. Instead you should move the code that you have that is checking the success value to inside the completion handler. Of course you could put it in a separate method and call that from inside your completion handler.

Comment: I am new to swift (and also new to the concept of completion handlers).  The performQuery's completion handler handles the success result doesn't it? Do I need another one? Can you elaborate a little further please.

Comment: indeed the completion handler is the piece of code that is called by the performQuery when the result is returned. Since this is an asynchronous call that completion handler will probably be called after the method has finished its work. So it the line 'loadSuccess = true' that you should replace with the logic that you now have after calling this function.

Comment: thank you. With your help and a bit of reading now I have more idea about the completion handlers.  They are called when all the functions code - including the background - is finished. `func load(completion:(result: Bool) -> Void)` is what I did and works great. I will vote up when the system lets me.  Thank you.